# PHP Page stops loading after script

Tags: php, html, loading

So this is a quick question I have about my php page. I wont put the code up because it would turn into solving the syntax. I was looking for the reason this happens.

This being, I have a .php page and it loads and about half way down and there is a short bit of php code. And in it, it echos to add a few items to a database. But then none of the rest of the html page loads.

Its a php type file.

Actually here is the part within the html.

```
<select id="price_select" name="priceBox">
    <?php
        ...
        //connects to database in code not shown
        $result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename")or die(mysql_error());  
        $count=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $price = $row['price'];
            if($price != NULL){
                ($count = $count+1);
            }
            echo "$(\"#price_select\").append('<option>" . $price . "</option>');";
        }
        if($count==0) {
            echo "$(\"#price_select\").append('<option>Out of Stock</option>');";   
        }                           
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: How many rows are returned from the query?

Comment: where is your opening and end <script></script>

Comment: Why you don't echo the `<option></option>` instead of using javascript to add the select box options??

Answer (score 1):

You have error on the following line:

```
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename")or die(mysql_error());
```

You must have similar:

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM $tablename")or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

You php code should be similar:

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM $tablename")or die(mysqli_error($link));

$count=0;

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $price = $row['price'];
        if($price != NULL){
            ($count = $count+1);
            echo "<option> $price </option>";
        }
    }
    if ($count === 0) 
    {
        echo "<option>Out of Stock</option>";
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing right with perpetuating wrong information.  `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and they don't work as substitutes.  Fix your error and I'll happily remove the vote.

Comment: And I just fixed it for you.  Please read the documentation next time.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like below.

```
$html = '';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $price = $row['price'];
    if($price != NULL){
        ($count = $count+1);
    }
    $html .= '<option>" . $price . "</option>';
}

if($count==0) {
    echo '<option>Out of Stock</option>';
} else {
    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code adding `<script>`-tag as follows:

```
<select id="price_select" name="priceBox">
    <?php
        ...
        //connects to database in code not shown
        $result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename")or die(mysql_error());  
        $count=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $price = $row['price'];
            if($price != NULL){
                ($count = $count+1);
            }
            echo "<script>$(\"#price_select\").append('<option>" . $price . "</option>');</script>";
        }
        if($count==0) {
            echo "<script>$(\"#price_select\").append('<option>Out of Stock</option>');</script>";   
        }                           
    ?>
</select>
```